# Tableau: Individual vs Population Scatterplot

Tags: tableau-api, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatterplot that shows a measure called adj_mac on the y axis, and position on the x axis. I need display two different sets of scatterplot points; one for the entire population (sts_pos) as a background, and one for a selected individual (irg_pos). The purpose is contrast an individual with an entire population.

I've tried creating a left join of the population and individual tables, added both the individual and population points as a measure; but I would need to be able to filter the individual points by subject_id and I cannot figure out how to do that. Or I would need to be able to color the null values in the subject id one color (the points in the population but not found in the selected individual).

The following picture shows where I started.

[image: individual vs population MAC]

After some great advice below and in [this post](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2012/7/filtering-parameters-18326), I did the following:

- Right clicked on my worksheet's Data tab
- Select "Create Parameter"
- Create a parameter called 'subject_param' that we will link to the value of Subject_ID using a calculated field:

  1. Data type = string
  2. Allowable Values = List
  3. Add from field > Subject ID
- Right click on the "Marks" page
- Click on "New Calculation"
- Enter [subject_param] = [Subject Id]
- Drag this new calculation to the Color box
- Select a color for each option
- Show the Subject ID filter

Now I just need to figure out how to do this without having to select "Null" (points that are in the overall population but not the selected person) from the subject id list and instead only have to plot the subject id.

[image]

Comment: Do all your individual points together equal your population? Try making a Parameter filter for your Subject_ID, then a field where [Subject_ID_parameter] = [Subject_ID] and put that on the color shelf. This will only highlight the subject that you select out of the parameter filter. More info here http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2012/7/filtering-parameters-18326 That will help you highlight one point out of all the points

Comment: You should be able to do this without using a Union or cartesian join to expand your dataset, at least as best I can tell from your description. Can you post a little sample data?

Comment: @Kara_F thanks for your suggestion; it has me close to the answer I need. I'm posting another picture in my question to show you where I'm stuck. 

In the final output, I will need a drop down to select a single subject ID, and instead of having to plot both 'Null' (rows with no subject id = in the population but not the individual) and the chosen Subject ID, I would like for 'Null' to always show. Hopefully the picture clarifies this.

Answer (score 1):

First to summarise what I understand you want to do:
You have a set of X dots for the whole population that you want to display and another set of Y dots per individual and you only want to display one of these individual sets at a time.
So individual is not a subset of population but rather a second set and your challenge is to show only one set and not all sets for every individual.

My solution will blow up your data set but in the end you will have what you asked for:

1. Join the data sources with a cartesian join: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm
2. put sts_pos and irg_pos in the worksheet (important: take the AVR and not the SUM, since you multiplied each row you will otherwise end up with a wrong plot)
3. Now you have all individuals and the whole population on the plot.
4. create a filter on Subject_ID and make it available as a single value list
5. Now you can filter all other individuals but the whole population stays the same
6. You will probably want to adjust the colour to have the population in one colour and individual in the other

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the data set is so large that a cartesian join would kill the entire server.